# How can server-side components communicate with client-side components in React?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, react-18, react-server-components

I'm working with Next.js and am testing their new way of data fetching but this can be a general React 18+ question too as the library itself is shifting towards a distinction between client and server components.

Suppose I have the setup:

```
// page.tsx (server component)
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Search /> {/* Search is a client component that tracks state for an input */}
      <ServerData /> {/* ServerData is a server component that gets the initial data */}
    </>
  )
}
```

Since `Search` tracks the `input` state, how can I use that value and do a **client-side** filter on `ServerData`?

What I've tried:
`Search` can be a client component that accepts a children prop. `page.tsx` can be restructured such that `SearchData` gets passed as a child to Search and `ServerData` can accept an input prop. This is likely not going to work since I cannot pass `input` to `ServerData` as `Search` only understands it as `children`.

Comment: Have you ever managed to find out how to do so? I'm basically having the same question.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you're attempting to conditionally present server components based on some state within a client component. [Next.js recommends passing server components as props to client components](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#nesting-server-components-inside-client-componentshttps://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#nesting-server-components-inside-client-components), which is sort of what you were attempting to do with the `children` prop. The problem with this approach is that the client component (in this case, `<Search>`) does not have access to any of the data associated with its individual `children` which it would need in order to perform filtering logic.

Since JSX can be passed as any prop, not just `children`, I recommend doing the following:

```js
// ServerListItem.tsx
type ServerListItemProps = {
  message: string;
};

export default function ServerListItem({ message }: ServerListItemProps) {
  return <li>{message}</li>;
}
```

```js
// ServerList.tsx
import ClientList from './ClientList';
import ServerListItem from './ServerListItem';

export default async function ServerList() {
  const data = await getData();

  const listItems = data.map((listItem) => ({
    message: listItem.message,
    content: <ServerListItem key={listItem.id} message={listItem.message} />,
  }));

  return <ClientList listItems={listItems} />;
}

const getData = () => Promise.resolve(serverData);
const serverData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    message: 'Item 1',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    message: 'Item 2',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    message: 'Item 3',
  },
];
```

```js
// ClientList.tsx
'use client';

import React from 'react';

type ClientListProps = {
  listItems: {
    message: string;
    content: React.ReactNode;
  }[];
};

export default function ClientList({ listItems }: ClientListProps) {
  const [filterInput, setFilterInput] = React.useState('');

  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setFilterInput(e.target.value);
  };

  const filteredItems = listItems
    .filter((listItem) => listItem.message.includes(filterInput))
    .map((listItem) => listItem.content);


  return (
    <>
      <input onChange={handleChange} placeholder="filter" />
      <ul>{filteredItems}</ul>
    </>
  );
}
```

In this example, the `<ServerList>` component is responsible for telling React to render each `<ServerListItem>` component on the server and the props it should receive. It then passes a list of objects to `<ClientList>`, each containing the server-rendered result of `<ServerListItem>` as well as the `message` to be used for filtering. `<ClientList>` knows it will receive the list of objects and can perform client-side filtering to determine which objects' `content` to display.

You would then render the `<ServerList>` component in your `page.tsx` file in `app/`:

```js
// page.tsx
import ServerList from './ServerList'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main>
      <ServerList />
    </main>
  );
}
```

Comment: There is a problem there because the filtering is happening on the client side. What if I want to send a request to get the server data that corresponds to the query? Maybe I have paginated data and I want to do a search on the whole db.

Answer (score 0):

Server components can simply pass props to client components. Note that these props have to be serializable. Event handlers, for example, don't work consequently.

See also: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#passing-props-from-server-to-client-components-serialization

> Props passed from the Server to Client Components need to be serializable
> . This means that values such as functions, Dates, etc, cannot be passed directly to Client Components.

Comment: The doc link has changed: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#passing-props-from-server-to-client-components-serialization